# Erros com versão .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Estou com erro de versão do .NET. Já instalei a versão .NET Core 1.1.2 e .NET Core 2.0.0, porém estou com esse erro e não consigo resolver.

Erro:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version 
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0' was not
found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at: \
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0'.
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro é referente a versão do seu projeto. Ele está configurado para a versão 1.0 do *.NET Core* e você tem a versão *1.1.2* e a *2.0* instalada.

Clique com o botão direito no seu projeto e selecione `Properties`.

Na tela aberta, selecione `Application` e depois altere a versão do *Framework* do seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê um *Rebuild* no seu projeto. **Pode ser que apareçam erros referentes a bibliotecas instaladas devido ao novo *Framework*.**